# How to get only Websphere MQ messages with a particular priority in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I'm currently developing an application in C# using the IBM Websphere MQ API (v7.5) whose main goal is to getting messages from a queue and store them in a database. All is well, I know to get and browse messages. But I must process messages differently according to their priority.

Is there any "simple" way to get only messages with a given priority ?

I don't want to use a dirty trick like browsing through all the messages, storing the ID of the messages I'm interested in, and then getting them one by one. I read in the MQ documentation that we can use a [selector string](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg20180_.htm) to browse through particular messages using an SQL like syntax, but I don't find how to do it in C#.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now in MQ .NET, you can use `MQC.MQMO_MATCH_MSG_ID` and `MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID` match options to get messages that match message id or correlation id. Getting messages matching a `Priority` is not available.

Alternatively you switch to using `XMS .NET`that allows consumers to be created with SQL92 style selection string. For example you can create consumer with a selection string `"JMSPriority > 3 AND manufacturer = 'Jaguar'"` to receive only messages that have `JMSPriority` of 3 and `manufacturer` name as Jaguar.